# how to resolve IndexError: list index out of range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on one question from Leetcode [2932. Maximum Strong Pair XOR I](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-strong-pair-xor-i/description/). but get the error `IndexError: list index out of range` under return statement. however I do not see the problem from line to line debugging.

```
    def maximumStrongPairXor(nums: List[int]) -> int:
        from itertools import combinations
        pair = list()
        for a, b in combinations(nums, 2):
            if abs(a- b) <= min(a, b):
                pair += [(a^b, a, b)]

        return sorted(pair)[-1][0
```

Answer (score 2):

`combinations` of 1-element array is an empty list, and this is a possibility in this task:

> `1 <= nums.length <= 50`

Which leads to `pair` being empty, which leads to IndexError in `sorted(pair)[-1]`

```
from itertools import combinations

list(combinations([1], 2))
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Comment: my test is failed under list `[1,2,3,4,5]` though

Answer (score 1):

Considering the constraints:

**`∣x−y∣ <= min(x,y)`**

It can be proven this equivalently means that `y` can't be more than `2*x` (and vice versa),

i.e. if `x=7` then `y<=14` to satisfy the constraint.

---

```
class Solution:
    def maximumStrongPairXor(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        pair=list()
        for i in nums :
            for j in nums: 
                if 4*i >= 2*j >= i:
                    pair.append(i^j)
        return max(pair)
```

---

Or in one line:

```
class Solution:
    def maximumStrongPairXor(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        return max(i^j for i in nums for j in nums if 4*i >= 2*j >= i)
```